# Thinkpad touchpad keeps randomly switching scroll methods

Tags: linux, touchpad, thinkpad, scrolling, input

The touchpad of my Thinkpad t440s keeps randomly switching between edge scrolling and two-finger scrolling under Arch Linux with KDE and X11. When I boot it up I never know which one it is going to be. The option in KDE's touchpad settings seemingly just gets ignored. It's pretty annoying, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot. This problem has persisted through system updates for at least half a year now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Lenovo has touch pad drivers for its various models. Is there a Linux version for your ThinkPad?

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after I installed xf86-input-synaptics, though I'm still wondering what would cause this strange behavior.